# Create a Variable to Conditionally Equal Another Cell's Value

Tags: sas

I have dataset with two variables 'shift' and 'scheduled'. The 'shift' variable contains a number of different time value records, for example "ED A 7a-4p"; the scheduled variable contains the number or days that shift is scheduled, so for example there would be a "3" in the cell to represent 3 days.

I created the following code to understand how many shifts are staffed at a given hour.

```
data ED_A_7a_4p; 
set schedule schedule10;
if shift = 'ED A 7a-4p' and Scheduled = '3' then SevenToEightAM = ???;
if shift = 'ED A 7a-4p' and Scheduled = '7' then EightToNineAM  = ???;
run;
```

I would like the created variables, for example 'SevenToEightAM', to equal the number that is in "scheduled" variable column. So if 'scheduled' is 3 I would want 'SevenToEightAM' to equal 3.

The issue is that 'scheduled' is totally random and I can't autocode it so I was hoping there is a conditional option in SAS that would allow me to make 'SevenToEightAM' to whatever "scheduled" is within my dataset.

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert a character string into a number?  If so look at the INPUT() function.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of this transformation. Why does the value of SCHEDULED determine both which variable to set AND what value to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a `TABULATE` report instead of creating new variables.  Try:

```
data have; 
  set original;
  scheduled_num = input(scheduled, best12.);
run;

Proc TABULATE data=have;
  class shift;
  var scheduled_num;
  table shift, scheduled*sum;
```